# How to update salable quantity of product from admin or programmatic in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, quantity, salable

I have got salable salable quantity of product in magento 2.3 using object manager.

> ```
> But we need to update quantity by programmatic or admin.
> ```

```
$getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');

$salable = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($sku);
                print_r($salable);
```

> Output like in below :

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [stock_name] => Default Stock
                [qty] => 0
                [manage_stock] => 1
            )

)
```

Comment: have u update salable quantity of products?

Answer (score 1):

**This is verified in Magento 2.3.2**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function yourMethod() {
    $sku = 'ABC123';
    $qty = 10;
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty); // this line
    $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
}
```

**Update Stock using ObjectManager**

Create a sandbox `script PHP file` in magento root dir and add below code

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$sku = 'demo';
$qty = 10;
$_sourceItemsSaveInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface');
$_sourceItemFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory');
$sourceItem = $_sourceItemFactory->create();
$sourceItem->setSourceCode('default'); // default : stock source
$sourceItem->setSku($sku);
$sourceItem->setQuantity($qty);
$sourceItem->setStatus(1);
$_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Error : Class Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterfac does not exist

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: After compile same error

Comment: @BaharuniAsif,  Check my updated answer. Let me know

Comment: I got solution thanks for reply @Supravat M

Comment: @BaharuniAsif, Pls accpect /vote for that. if its realy help you. It may be help for other al well.

Comment: this code updates the quantity, not salable quantity. 
I want to update scalable quantity? how can I do this @SupravatMondal

Comment: @HafizArslan I'm also facing a same issues, please share if you find a solution for you question.